# create Lambda Expression with reflection in c#

Tags: c#, reflection

I need to Create the following Lambda Expression :

```
{d=>d.Name.NameEn}
```

I wrote the following code:

```
ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "d");
MemberExpression memberExpression = Expression.Property(parameter, typeof(T).GetProperty("Name"));
LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(memberExpression, parameter);
```

Output :

```
{d => d.Name}
```

But I need this :

```
{d=>d.Name.NameEn}
```

How to make this ?

update:

my class :

```
 public class T
    {
        public U Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class U
    {
        public string NameEn { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you need to wrap the expression in another MemberExpression, e.g.:

```
var outerMemberExpression = Expression.Property(memberExpression, typeof(U).GetProperty("NameEn"));
```

and use that for your lambda expression. You do have two member access expressions there, after all: One to access `Name`, and one to access `NameEn`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "d");
MemberExpression memberExpression = 
    Expression.Property(parameter, typeof(T).GetProperty("Name"));
MemberExpression memberExpressionInner = 
    Expression.Property(memberExpression,
                        typeof(T).GetProperty("Name").PropertyType.GetProperty("NameEn"));
LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(memberExpressionInner, parameter);
```

Or, if `U` is known at runtime (I was assumming `T` would be a generic parameter before your update), the third line could be:

```
MemberExpression memberExpressionInner = 
    Expression.Property(memberExpression, typeof(U).GetProperty("NameEn"));
```